# Make Submenu on sidebar component Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, sidebar

So it to loop and subMenu on sidebar component, but instead of the subMenu showUp under the parents menu, it showUp on the Right side of the parents menu as pic below:
[image]

here is my code on how i try to loop the subMenu and The parents item to the react component:

```
return (
    <div className=" my-4 border-gray-100 pb-4">
      {items.map(({ icon: Icon, iconArrow: IconArrow, ...item }, index) => {
        if (item.subMenu) {
          return (
            <div>
              <Link href={item.link}>
                <a
                  onClick={(e) => onMouseClick(e, item.link)}
                  className="flex mb-2 justify-start items-center gap-4 pl-5 hover:bg-gray-900 p-2 rounded-md group cursor-pointer hover:shadow-lg m-auto"
                >
                  <Icon className="text-2xl text-white group-hover:text-red" />
                  <h3 className="text-base text-white group-hover:text-red font-semibold  ">
                    {item.label}
                  </h3>
                  {item.subMenu && dropdown ? (
                    <>
                      <IconArrow className="pl-0 text-2xl text-white group-hover:text-red" />
                    </>
                  ) : (
                    <></>
                  )}{" "}
                  {item.subMenu && dropdown ? (
                    <div>
                      {item.subMenu.map((subitem, index) => {
                        return <>makan</>;
                      })}
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    <></>
                  )}
                </a>
              </Link>
            </div>
          );
        } else {
          return (
            // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key
            <div>
              <Link href={item.link}>
                <a
                  onClick={(e) => onMouseClick(e, item.link)}
                  className="flex mb-2 justify-start items-center gap-4 pl-5 hover:bg-gray-900 p-2 rounded-md group cursor-pointer hover:shadow-lg m-auto"
                >
                  <Icon className="text-2xl text-white group-hover:text-red" />
                  <h3 className="text-base text-white group-hover:text-red font-semibold  ">
                    {item.label}
                  </h3>
                </a>
              </Link>
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Can Some one tell me where did i do wrong here, here is where i call the sidebar component into the sidebar:

```
 return (
    <div className="h-full px-4 pt-8  bg-yellow flex flex-col  peer-focus:left-0 peer:transition ease-out delay-150 duration-200">
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-start item-center mb-4">
        <Image src={Logo_Nabati} width={123} height={75} alt="logo Nabati" />
      </div>
      <Sidebarcomponent items={menuItems} />;
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: this is a css problem.

Comment: @Layhout i've been trying to figure it out but still have problem on that..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
return (
    <div className=" my-4 border-gray-100 pb-4 relative">
      {items.map(({ icon: Icon, iconArrow: IconArrow, ...item }, index) => {
        if (item.subMenu) {
          return (
            <div className="absolute top-full left-0">...</div>
          );
        } else {...})}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: it dissapread from the web

Comment: and it not showing the sub menu under the Menu

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to display the submenu under the "Master Data"? Put the component under it. Then in the anchor tag you have a flex. Add flex-col to change the direction of flex, top-bottom.

Comment: yes, but you can explained more detail about it?..